# Enviar JSON por POST con php a un webservice

Tags: php, webservice

**Situacion:**

Tengo un script con php en el cual estoy recibiendo algunos datos, con esos datos creo un JSON y ese JSON necesito mandarlo por POST con php5 (puro, no framework) a un web service en un sitio online.

Encontre que se puede hacer con php5-curl, pero como es un servicio de hostinig en el que esta el sitio, no puedo instalar esos paquetes.

**Mi pregunta:**

Hay forma de hacer ese envio del JSON solo usando php? y si es asi, me podrian decir como hacerlo o donde o como buscarlo? porque unicamente encuentro como hacero pero con php5-curl.

---

Muchas gracias, pero me referia un poquito mas como a esto, pero igual gracias por responder :)

```
$postData = array(
    'kind' => 'blog',
    'blog' => '3',
    'title' => 'A new post',
    'content' => 'With <b>exciting</b> content...'
);

// Create the context for the request
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Authorization: application/json\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'content' => json_encode($postData)
    )
));

// Send the request
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/blogger/blog/posts/', FALSE, $context);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die('Error');
}
```

Ahora el detalle que tengo es que siempre entra a la condicion, es decir que siempre me regresa false, no estoy seguro si es el webservices el que esta regresando eso o ni siquiera intenta hacer el envio del json, sugerencias? 
Ayuda please! :C

En esta linea es en donde no se que es lo que hace, si no sale el envio o el servicio web me regresa eso... yo le voy mas a que no hace el envio de datos.

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/blogger/blog/posts/', FALSE, $context);
```

le di un var_dump al `$response` y me regresa `bool(false)`

Comment: Por qué estás usando ```"Authorization: application/json\r\n"```. Que pasa si hacés esa misma llamada por CURL? no php-curl si no CURL desde tu terminal, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, en los últimos proyectos que he trabajado, quería devolver por JSON datos desde el backend en PHP. Lo normal es que fueran resultados de una base de datos o algo por el estilo.

Para estos casos, sin usar frameworks, yo creo un array con los datos que necesito devolver y luego simplemente utilizo

```
echo json_encode(miArray);
```

para devolverlos al sitio que lo pidió (muchas veces una petición `$.post` de jQuery).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, eso que comentaste me dio una idea de que buscar y ahora ya se como hacerlo pero hora tengo otro problemilla que acabo de publicar...
Tienes alguna sugerencia, idea o algo similar para eso?

Comment: Acabo de revisar tu código; aparentemente está todo bien, de hecho, está igual que en los ejemplos de la documentación. Seguramente habrá algo por ahí que se escape...

Answer (score 1):

la función **file_get_contents**(...) debería encerrarse entre un **try**...**catch** para el manejo de los posibles errores:

```
try {
  // Send the request
  $response = file_get_contents(...);
  // Check for errors
  if($response === false){
    die('Error');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!
Respondo con el fin de servir de referencia a alguien en el futuro. La mejor manera (y la más sencilla) de ejecutar peticiones a servicios web rest con json es usar la librería de [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Con esta puedes manejar a la perfección cualquier petición http por cualquiera de los métodos, con un sencillo control de cabeceras y cuerpo, además de que el objeto respuesta se puede desglosar para usarlo como mejor te convenga.

Según el ejemplo en la pregunta, el uso sería así:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
     'kind' => 'blog',
     'blog' => '3',
     'title' => 'A new post',
     'content' => 'With <b>exciting</b> content...'
    $response = $client->post("http://www.example.com/blogger/blog/posts/", array(
        'body' => json_encode($payload)
    ))->getBody();

    $responseArray= json_decode($response, true);  // Si la rta es JSON 
    var_dump($responseArray); // acá ves lo que devuelve el web service.
```

Saludos.